# ElasticSeach query to retrieve all tags for books

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an ElasticSearch database and I have `Books` and `Tags` documents. A book can have multiple tags.

Here the C# class for the book:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "Book")]
public class Book
{
    [Keyword(Store = false)]
    public string Id{ get; set; }

    [Keyword(Store = false)]
    public string CoverColor{ get; set; } 

    public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the ElasticSearch document for the tag:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "Tag")]
public class Tag
{
    [Keyword(Store = false)]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [Keyword(Store = false)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

This is the JSON version of one of the Book documents:

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "Book",
  "_id": "4d43345fffereredwerw324",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": "123456",
    "coverColor": "Red",
    "tags": [
      {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "fantasy"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Science fiction"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'd like to have is a query which retrieves all the book colors without repetition (let's say I have two Red's and four Green's, I should get 1 Red and 1 Green) and for each color I should get the lists of associated tags (e.g. all the tags under the same color, basically)

The ideal JSON output:

```
result = [
{
   coverColor: "Red",
   tags: [{ id:1, name:"Fantasy"}, {id: 4, name:"Science fiction"}, {id:33, name:"Novel"}]
},
{
   coverColor: "Green",
   tags: [{id: 4, name:"Science fiction"}]
},
{
   coverColor: "White",
   tags: []
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a Terms aggregation I believe. Something like.

```
var result = client.Search<Book>(s => s
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("colour_agg", st => st
            .Field(o => o.CoverColor)
            .Size(10)
            .ExecutionHint(TermsAggregationExecutionHint.Ordinals)
        )
    )
);
```

this is then retrieved from the results set thus:

```
var agg = result.Aggs.Terms("colour_agg");
```

The request looks something like:

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "colour_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CoverColor",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: brilliant! could you please tell me the kibana version of the query so I can test it and tweak it if needed.. many thanks :-)

Comment: In the edited answer... you added the tags aggregation to the question after I answered. That is a bit more complex. You will need to read up on 'nested aggregations' and possibly 'reverse nested aggregations'. But this should get you started.

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini you can get the serialized query json using `.OnRequestCompleted()` along with `.DisableDirectStreaming()` on `ConnectionSettings`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-on-request-completed.html or using `.SerializeToString()` on `IElasticClient.Serializer` and pass it the search request/descriptor

Comment: @RussCam Hi Russ, glad to hear from you again! I upvoted the question but it doesn't actually solve my issue which looks like it's requiring some sort of nested aggregation, would you like to have a look at it?